# How to make SSH connection to remote terminal with a custom init script?

Tags: ssh

> Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/626574/1952991

I need to go to a specific directory on remote machine after I made SSH connection:

```bsh
local:~$ ssh myserver
remote:~$ cd foo/bar
remote:~/foo/bar$
```

How can pass the `cd foo/bar` as an init script to my shell command so I don't have to type `cd foo/bar` after login?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any comand that you want to init after logon into `.bashrc` (if you are using bash)

f.e.
`cd /home/mirek/Downloads` at EOF will result going straight into `/home/mirek/Downloads` directory (upon logging/executing new shell):

`mirek@T480:~/Downloads$`